# Border-radius for Modal in Ant design

Tags: antd

I want to set a **border-radius** for my **Modal** with an **inline style** in **ant design**(I use ant design Modal). I try these ways for my Modal component but they don't work :

`bodyStyle={{ borderRadius: '20px' }}`

`style={{ borderRadius: '20px' }}`

there is a solution for Modal border-radius :`.ant-modal-content { overflow: auto; border-radius: 24px }` but it changes all of the Modals in my project. I want to assign a border-radius only for one Modal.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late to answer this question, but one way of doing, is to give a `className` to the modal that you want to be affected like this :

```
<Modal
  className='affected-modal'
  title="test title"
  open={isModalOpen}
  onOk={handleOk}
  onCancel={handleCancel}>

  {/* modal content */}
  
</Modal>
```

And then give the style to `.ant-modal-content` through its parent class which is `.affected-modal`. So this style is especially for the modal that you want to change its `border-radius`:

```
.affected-modal .ant-modal-content {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
}
```

By the way, don't forget to put `!important` at the end of the `border-radius` value. I hope it can help you.